# Find cell value greater than zero and copy to another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want to check if Col `B` cell value is greater than zero, if yes, I want to copy the whole row to another worksheet. 
My code is given below, it works but i want to improve it because I hard-code with `A65000`. Please advise how to check Col `B` cell until the last filled data.

```
Sub Search_Number()
    'copy row if cell greater than zero
    Dim i As Range

    Sheets("HVM").Select

    For Each i In Range("I:I")
        If i.Value > 0 Then
            i.Select
            ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Blocked").Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial

        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: what does A65000 mean?

Comment: Dim lRow As Long Dim ws1 As Worksheet Set ws1 As ActiveWorksheet  lRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row is the standard way to find last row. I have used column A i.e. 1, you can use whichever column is representative of the filled data.

Comment: Your question text says "I want to check if Col B ..." but your code is looping through column "I" cells...

Answer (score 0):

this code checks if the value in column b is greater than 0 on sheet1 and copies the entire row to sheet2 to the first blank row in column a.  this code assumes you have no header rows and the data begins in row 1 and you want the entire row pasted to another sheet starting in row 1.  finally, this code works only if sheet1 is the source to copy from, and sheet 2 is the blank sheet to copy to.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim lr As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheet1
Set ws2 = Sheet2

lr = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = ws1.Range("b1:b" & lr)

For Each cell In rng
  If cell.Value > 0 Then
    cell.EntireRow.Copy
    ws2.Select
    If ws2.Range("A1").Value = "" Then
      ws2.Range("a1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Else
      Cells((Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row) + 1, "a").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
  End If
Next cell

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```